# Array of Pointers and address spacing

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[4]={1,2,3,4};
    int *p[4]={a,a+1,a+2,a+3};
    printf("%u %u %u\n",p,(p+1),(p+2));    
}
```

And the output is:

```
937449104 937449112 937449120
```

On line 3:

This will store the addresses of a[] and its address spacing is 4 values apart as expected.

On line 6:

But when I print the addresses of the elements in p, shouldn't                                      even their address differ by 4 since they are ints as well.

But the output gives us address spacing of 8.

Comment: `p` is an array of pointers! Each element is a pointer which means it holds addresses not `ints`!

Comment: @SaumitraKulkarni Can you provide the information related to OS, OS architecture(32 bit or 64-bit) and compiler version? I tried at my local and different online IDEs, but not able to produce the scenario from provided code.

Comment: linux ubuntu 32bit gcc compiler

Comment: The program has undefined behavuiour. You **must** use `%p` format when printing pointers, and you **must** cast them to `void*` when passing to `printf`.

Comment: It doesn't look like a 32 bit compiler.

Comment: sorry its 64bit

Answer (score 2):

Note that `p` is an array of `int*` (pointers), not an array of integers. So on a 64-bit system, it's perfectly normal for pointers to have a spacing of 8, or more precisely, `sizeof(int*)`.

```
int *p[4]={a,a+1,a+2,a+3};
    ^
printf("%u %u %u\n",p,(p+1),(p+2));
                    ^  ^     ^
```

When you write `p+1` (use `p` in pointer arithmetics), the array `p` decays to a pointer, so the type for `p+1` is `int**`, which should be a pointer **to a pointer** to int. You'll observe 4 (or `sizeof(int)`) if you dereference `p`, getting its content:

```
printf("%u %u %u\n",*p,*(p+1),*(p+2));
                    ^  ^      ^
```

which is equivalent to:

```
printf("%u %u %u\n",a,(a+1),(a+2));
                    ^  ^     ^
```

By the way, your compiler should have warned you about wrong format specifier, so this is the correct statement:

```
printf("%p %p %p\n",*p,*(p+1),*(p+2));
printf("%p %p %p\n",,a,(a+1),(a+2));
         ^  ^  ^
```

Note that `%p` is the correct specifier if you want to print the address of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The increment of a pointer in pointer arithmetic is dictated by what the pointer points to. Here in `p+1` `p` will convert ("decay") into pointer to the first element of the array, which (decayed pointer) is of type `int**`, because the first element being of type `int*`. Now when we write `p+1` it will move by what `p` points to — which means move by `sizeof(int*)`. And in your system `sizeof(int*)=8`. (You have likely to have 64 bit system — the `sizeof` resulting in 8 byte or 64 bit).

At this point it should be clear why it gave the spacing of `8` in the second case.

Check what happens in first case. `a` converts ("decays") into pointer to the first element, which (decayed pointer) is of type `int*`, the first element being of type `int`. So here `a+1` will move by sizeof what it points to which is size of the `int` variable or `sizeof(int)`.

The printed values will differ by `4` in a system *where `sizeof(int*) == 4`* which is *certainly* not the case in your system. Understanding the declaration here solves the half of the doubt you have — both are distinct in that, the first one is an array of 4 `int` but the second is an array 4 `int*`. When in doubt about declarations, you can check with [`cdecl`](https://cdecl.org/).

The correct way to print pointers is to use `%p` format specifier with explicit `void*` casting. Example: `printf("%p\n",(void*)p);` Also, you can check the size of `int` variable and `int*` variables like this (and doing this will make you aware of the size of the `int` and `int*` in your system).

```
printf("sizeof(int)=%zu sizeof(int*)=%zu\n", sizeof(int), sizeof(int*));
```

<sup>`%zu` used because `sizeof` operator returns the results in `size_t`.</sup>

Cutting a long story short — the takeaways will be:

1. Pointer arithmetic is dependent on the object it points to.
2. For the same arithmetic operation `p+1`, the result will be different depending on the type `p` points to.
3. Correctly printing pointer variables and `size_t` values.